# How to print a number within a string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I would like to use the command `text` to type numbers within 57 hexagons. I want to use a loop:

```
for mm=1:57
    text(x(m),y(m),'m')
end
```

where `x(m)` and `y(m)` are the coordinates of the text .
The script above types the string "m" and not the value of `m`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look up the [`num2str`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

Jubobs pretty much told you how to do it.  Use the [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) function. BTW, small typo in your `for` loop.  You mean to use `mm`:

```
for mm=1:57
    text(x(mm),y(mm),num2str(mm));
end
```

The reason why I've even decided to post an answer is because you can do this vectorized without a loop, which I'd also like to write an answer for.  What you can do place each number into a character array where each row denotes a unique number, and you can use `text` to print out all numbers simultaneously.

```
m = sprintfc('%2d', 1:57);
d = reshape([m{:}], 2, 57).';
text(x, y, d);
```

The (undocumented!) function [`sprintfc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) takes a formatting specifier and an array and creates a cell array of strings where each cell is the string version of each element in the array you supply.  In order to ensure that the character array has the same number of columns per row, I ensure that each string takes up 2 characters, and so any number less than 10 will have a blank space at the beginning.  I then convert the cell array of strings into a character array by converting the cell array into a comma-separated list of strings and I reshape the matrix into an acceptable form, and then I call `text` with all of the pairs of `x` and `y`, with the corresponding labels in `m` together on the screen.

Comment: @mohamed - My pleasure.  If you no longer need help, please accept my answer by going to the top of my post, and clicking on the checkmark icon to the left, below the up and down voting arrows.  Thanks!